# Infinite scroll, destroy and recreate elements when scrolling

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs, yii2

I know this might be a popular question, but I'd like to ask for advice from experts here specifically for my problem.

My webpage represents a Tree (meaning vegetation) with infinite scroll, e.g. the middle part of the tree - the image, is iterative and the number of iterations depends on my datasource.

So, the datasource is user records that will be represented as leaves on the tree. There are exactly `n` leaves for each middle part of the tree, and **each leaf** has `onClick` ajax listener:
[image]

I know I could append elements to my container as user scrolls down, but the problem is that even though rows at the top of the list become invisible as they scroll out of the view, they are still a part of the page and still consume resources. So the web app slows down and the listeners may not work properly.

I'm looking for any plugin that dynamically destroys elements as they become invisible and recreating them if they become visible again.

I've almost found a solution [angular ui-scroll directive](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll) but not sure how to apply it. Here is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBKxaX), your forks would be highly appreciated.

My page now is working like this without dynamic loading:

```
foreach($leaves as $i=>$leaf)
{
     if($i % NUM_OF_LEAVES == 0)
     {
         echo "<div class='tree-section'>";
         echo '<img class="part" src="'.Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/images/tree_center.png"/>';  
             echo '<div class="leaves">'; 

             for($j = 0; $j<NUM_OF_LEAVES ; $j++)
             {
                 if(isset($leaves[$i + $j])){
                     //show leaf $leaves[$i + $j]
                 }
             }
             echo '</div>';
         echo '</div>';
      }
  }
```

Comment: have you had a play with `angular-ui-scroll`'s demos? http://rawgit.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/master/demo/serviceDatasource/serviceDatasource.html a service based approach, or even an inscope with a single data fetch solution may be perfect for what you're after

Comment: @haxxxton, thank you, could you please have a look at this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBKxaX, the implementation is just what I need, but I'm not sure how to adjust it to my problem

Answer (score 0):

Setting up a service that returns the data you need when called rather than pre-rendering it would be ideal. [Their service demo](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-scroll/blob/master/demo/serviceDatasource/serviceDatasource.js) provides a `get` function, you should replace this get function with a `$http` call to your server, to have it return to you just the tree pieces your need (sort of like paginating a response).

An untested example of this would be something like

```
angular.module('application', ['ui.scroll', 'ui.scroll.jqlite'])
    .factory('datasource', ['$http',
        function ($http) {

            var get = function(index, count, success){
                // gets data from /datasourceapi/tree/?index=XXX <-- XXX is the offset from the beginning
                return $http({
                    url:'/datasourceapi/tree/',
                    method: 'GET',
                    params:{index: index}
                }).then(function(response){
                    return success(response);
                });
            }

            return {
                get: get,
            };
        }
    ]);
```